# DTDLとEnumの一覧を渡されたのでそれをjsonに書き起こしたい。

Tags: json

DTDLにC#の構造体（？）を渡す要件があって、それをjson形式でAPIで渡すことになりました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/digital-twins/concepts-models
エクセルには左にDTDL、右にEnumの変数が書かれていて、そのまま手でjsonに書き起こすことは可能です。
しかし、万が一手入力ミスで別のを指定してしまうとよくないので、できるだけ自動的に入力したいです。
ネット上ではDBからJsonに書き起こす方法はあったものの、階層的な表からのやりかたは記載ありませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

図のように、右がいままでの形式で、左が新しい要件の形式です。
１つ１つやっていくと時間がかかるので、エクセルの集計か、簡単なプログラムなどで解決する方法をご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: 「手で書き起こすことは可能」であれば後は愚直にプログラムに落とし込むだけだと思いますが、何に困っているかをもう少し具体的に説明した方が回答がつきやすいと思います。今の質問内容だとやりたいことが書かれているだけで「代わりに誰かプログラムを書いて欲しい」という印象を与えます。

Comment: 私はプログラマではないのですが、困っていることはすでに書いたつもりです。気分を害したならすみません。上の要件を解決するキーワードを知っていれば教えて欲しかったです。

Comment: パッと読んだ限りだとただ JSON を別の JSON に変換するだけのタスクに見えたので、どこを説明すれば良いのか考えています。動かなくても良いので、試しているコードを [edit] して追記いただくことは可能でしょうか（参考：[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)）。同時に、ひとつひとつやっていくというのが、今までの形式で表されたデータがたくさんあってひとつずつという意味なのか、データの種類がたくさんあってひとつずつという意味なのか、コードを通してそのあたりも明快になりそうです。